# Update Label in Tkinter when calling function

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a Tkinter GUI and I would like to update the status of the script in a Label, writing which function is being called, but I am having problems with that.
I have already seen many answers on here, but still I cant come to a solution. This is the part of the code that I am working on:

```
run_script(username, password):
    text = StringVar()
    text.set('')
    l=Label(master, text=text, fg='blue')
    l.grid(row=6) #I would like the Label in the row 6
    l.pack()
    text.set('calling my function1')
    my_file.my_function1(username, password)
    text.set('calling my function2')
    my_file.my_function2()

master = Tk()
username = Entry(master, name='username', width=30)
password = Entry(master, name='password', show='*', width=30)
username.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10,2))
password.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)
def call_report(username, password):
    run_script(username, password)
Button(master, text='start script',
   command= lambda:call_report(username.get(), password.get(),)).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
mainloop()
```

The program run perfectly, just the label is not updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution that can be used as example:

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def run_script():
    text = StringVar()
    l = Label(master, textvariable=text, fg='blue').grid(row=6)
    text.set('calling my function1')
    master.update()
    sleep(2)
    text.set('end of function1')

def call_report():
    run_script()


if __name__ == '__main__':
   master = Tk()
   username = Entry(master, name='username', width=30)
   password = Entry(master, name='password', show='*', width=30)
   username.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10,2))
   password.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

  button = Button(master, text='start script', command=lambda: call_report())
  button.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)

  master.mainloop()
```

I've changed `text` to `textvariable` in `Label`, and I added `master.update()`. In this way it force the GUI to redraw. Just to test if the GUI was changing, I tested with `sleep`. It is possible to update more time (for example before calling a function).

Comment: Your answer would be much better if you explained what you did. Otherwise we have to compare your code to the code in the question line by line and character by character to see what you changed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will now

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it, using the keyword argument `textvariable`:

```
import tkinter as tk


def run_script(username, password):
    text = tk.StringVar()
    text.set('')
    lab = tk.Label(master, textvariable=text, fg='blue')
    lab.grid(row=6)
    text.set('calling my function1')
    # call functions here

def call_report(username, password):
    run_script(username, password)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    master = tk.Tk()
    username = tk.Entry(master, name='username', width=30)
    password = tk.Entry(master, name='password', show='*', width=30)
    username.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=(10,2))
    password.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

    button = tk.Button(master, text='start script', command=lambda: call_report(username.get(), password.get(),))
    button.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=10)

    master.mainloop()
```

#### Note:

The use of `pack` and `grid` geometry managers in the same widget is not encouraged.
Please `import tkinter as tk`: adding `tk.` is a small price to keep the namespace clean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it still doesnt work. I tried just that part of code in adding `text.set('calling my function1')
    sleep(5)
    text.set('end of function1')` and it shows just `end of function1` after 5 seconds

Comment: I work with python 2.7 and I import tkinter in this way: `from Tkinter import *`

Comment: @Joe You shouldn't use sleep with tkinter. If you wish to add a delay, use the `.after` method instead. That will give the GUI the opportunity to refresh the screen.

Comment: @scotty3785 ok, thanks. Do you have any clue why doesnt the text is not updated(in the code without `sleep`)?

Comment: @Joe You could try `master.update()` after you set the text. That should force a GUI redraw.

Comment: @scotty3785 Thanks, the short example seems to work, I will try in the real code now

Comment: It works also in my code, but it gives me this error in the end `can't invoke "event" command:  application has been destroyed
    while executing
"event generate $w <<ThemeChanged>>"
    (procedure "ttk::ThemeChanged" line 6)
    invoked from within
"ttk::ThemeChanged"` What does cause it?